# How can 'discriminator' column be avoidable in Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I avoid creating a column as "Discriminator" inside the database , If I inherit my business class from model class ( model class is mapped on database table).

Because, at the moment, if I inherit my business class ( e.g Specifics) to an existing model class ( i.e DataSpecific ), It asks for code first migration. In the migration, I can see discriminator as new column. I really don't want this. Because, original model class is being used in the whole application and that code works fine.

How can I stop the creation of "descriminator" column

C# Code :

**Model Class**

```
public class DataSpecific
{

}
```

**Busines Class**

```
public class Specific
{

}
```

as a result I can see following code in the migration

```
 AddColumn("dbo.Consignments", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: That's because you're using TPH (Table per Hierarchy). Opt for TPT or TPC and you'll avoid the `Discriminator` column. See https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Is there any fluent api command or way by which we can instruct entity framerwork to use TPT or TPC?

Comment: Yes. That would be `ToTable("...")`. See https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either apply [`NotMapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMappedAttribute.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) Data Annotation to your business class:

```
[NotMapped]
public class Specific : DataSpecific
{
}
```

or use [`Ignore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Ignore%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<Specific>();
```